# How can I save opened application settings in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, hibernate

In Linux there is an option to save the currently opened windows such that when you shutdown and boot later, these applications are there the way you left them. It is similar to Hibernate in Windows.

Is there something similar in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at two different things.

1) Shutdown and boot - get your same apps as per Linux option - see @Am1rr3zA

2) Hibernate - OSX does this already. Just choose sleep from the apple menu
For more details see [Macworld explanation](http://www.macworld.com/article/53471/2006/10/sleepmode.html) and [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Relaunch](http://wiredupandfiredup.co.uk/Relaunch/) application for this purpose:

[Relaunch](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/30839) saves you time by taking Snapshots of which applications you are using, and starts them back up for you. Think of it as a launcher on steroids that lets you switch between work contexts with one click.

you can take a snapshot before restart your system and after that double click on the snapshot you created then it restored all your files and application you worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. I found a widget that does what I'm looking for. Now I can do a "hibernate" similar to the one in Windows. The widget puts the Mac in deep sleep. Even if I pull the power cord, when i start the Mac, it will show how I exactly left it.

Comment: http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/26521/super-sleeper that application allows you to set it and forget. It’s discontinued but available for download and still works in Snow Leopard.